# How to enable my game for Xbox Live Creators access

Tags: xbox-live

You are trying to enable your game for Xbox Live Creators access but you cannot find the Xbox Live link on Dev Center.

Answer (score 1):

To enable your game for Xbox Live Creators access, you need to make sure that the product category is set to “Games”, before you can see the “Xbox Live” link on the left navigation bar.

To change the category of your product to “Games”:

1. Click “Submissions”
2. Select the latest submission or create a new one
3. Click “Properties”
4. Under “Category and subcategory”, select “Games” as the category for your product, and save the change.

Now on the left navigation bar, under “Services”, you will see a new link “Xbox Live”.  Click that link to navigate to the Xbox Live setup page, and follow the instructions at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/create-and-test-a-new-creators-title

Comment: Don't forget the step to click "Test".  This provisions your live services into operation and add some test accounts (use your own Live ID if you wish), so long as they also have a gamertag associated (just browse to Xbox.com and login with that ID)

Answer (score 0):

If that does not work, even after you selected Games, delete the submission and start a new submission for your game. Xbox Live should appear then

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed now. There was a bug on the Developer Store dashboard which has now been fixed.

So you can now access the "Xbox Live" session under the services section now when you create your app.

However, your game submission must use the Category of "Games" for it to be accepted and work.

Hope this helps.